# how to make changes to config file permanently in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, config

In Laravel using `Config:set('database.connections.mysql.host','localhost')` make changes to the config file temporarily for the current user only, and it also does not make changes to the config file also. How can I make changes to the config file permanently so that it affects all users and if I opens the config file the I get the changed values.

Comment: Read/write the file, or use another persistance method like storing config items in a db

Comment: This seems to do what you want: https://github.com/daftspunk/laravel-config-writer

Comment: I faced same problem when I wanted to save custom settings(Enable/disable home page pop up) to a file. But I thought it is a bad idea to save frequently changing custom settings to file as this will add unnecessary noise to a GIT history. So I ended up using database table for storing all such configs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should just go to the config file itself and set it manually there.
if what you want is to dynamically set a config variable permanently then i recommend https://github.com/Phil-F/Setting/

Note that this will not change any of the laravel config. Instead it creates a json based config alongside, though it can also do clever stuff like use laravel config as a fallback option.

As for https://github.com/daftspunk/laravel-config-writer, i was unable to get this working.